# Sending text/form from jQuery SVG? Possible?

Tags: jquery, html, webforms, svg, html5-canvas

I have a jQuery SVG web application. Inside this application I would like to get a text (in a text box, like sending a comment to a website) and send it to my php application.

the question is how to send data via jQuery SVG? is it a form like HTML? how to go it?

Thank you!

Elik

Answer (score 1):

In order to create this effect, you're going to have to access the DOM nodes and parse data.

Say you have an svg text element:

```
 <text id="comment-box-1" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" font-size="12" x="0" y="0">This is a comment</text>
```

You can simply grab the data like this:

```
 var comment_1 = document.getElementById('comment-box-1').textContent;
```

Then you can submit this data (comment_1) to your php application any way you see fit.